# Yahoo SMTP server throws 500 series error only after DATA part is send

Tags: email, smtp, yahoo

If i send an invalid emailaddress via SMTP to gmail, after mailFrom and rcptTo. If rcptTo address is invalid, gmail sends 550 User not found. But yahoo is sending user not found only after DATA part is send. Is there any way to find email validity before DATA part

Comment: There is no way to find if an email address is valid besides trying to send email. Allowing people to check would open the door for misuse by spammers. Make sure you only email people that signed up for your emails and remove invalid emails from your list.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Validating user after rcpto send is not mandatory. It is up to developers choice whether to validate user before DATA part or after. Please refer to this https://www.freesoft.org/CIE/RFC/1123/92.htm
If you want to validate user before DATA, you can use third party email validators and clean your contact list and then send for only validate users